# Modifying an index.aspx file and then getting a http 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've been playing with a jQuery grid control, and made the following change to the index.aspx file:

From this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
              url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
              datatype: 'json',
              mtype: 'POST',
              colNames: ['Id', 'Votes', 'Title'],
              colModel: [
          { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Votes', index: 'Votes', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 400, align: 'left'}],
              pager: jQuery('#pager'),
              rowNum: 10,
              rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
              sortname: 'Id',
              sortorder: "desc",
              viewrecords: true,
              imgpath: '',
              caption: 'My first grid'
          });
      }); 
    </script>
```

To this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
              jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
              url: '/Home/GridData/',
              datatype: 'json',
              mtype: 'POST',
              colNames: ['Id', 'Votes', 'Title'],
              colModel: [
          { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Votes', index: 'Votes', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 400, align: 'left'}],
              pager: jQuery('#pager'),
              rowNum: 10,
              rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
              sortname: 'Id',
              sortorder: "desc",
              viewrecords: true,
              imgpath: '',
              caption: 'My first grid'
          });
      }); 
    </script>
```

Now I'm finding that whenever I load the project I get a HTTP 404 error, and am a bit taken aback by the problem: I changed the action that the page is supposed to load.

When I change it back the error persists.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Does `GridData` exist as an action?

Comment: @Curt Not only that, but is it marked as `[HttpPost]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, your first action was `DynamicGridData`.
You've changed that to the `GridData`
So you must [declare an action](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/22/cleaning-up-posts-in-asp-net-mvc/) `GridData`, and mark it with [`HttpPost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GridData(SomeEditModel form)
{
    if (IsNotValid)
    {
        return ShowAView(form);
    }

    DoActualWork();

    return RedirectToSuccessPage();
}
```

Comment: @Tom Kealy did you try `/Home/GridData/` in browser? Is error still there?

Comment: I keep on seeing this intermittently regardless of what I do. It occurs after modifying the Index.cshtml page.

Comment: Yep. Rebuild, with no errors - same error. Also reverting to a known working version doesn't seem to help.